# Why does the device stop recieving locations on iOS after two minutes gps on?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, location

```
// Create a location manager object
self.locationManagerTest = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

// Set the delegate
self.locationManagerTest.delegate = self;

// Request location authorization
[self.locationManagerTest requestAlwaysAuthorization];

// Specify the type of activity your app is currently performing
self.locationManagerTest.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

// Start location updates
[self.locationManagerTest startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.after 2 weeks struggling on this problem finally solved it. Just needed to check apple documentation. I just needed to add two lines:

```
self.locationManagerTest = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
// Set the delegate
self.locationManagerTest.delegate = self;
// Request location authorization
[self.locationManagerTest requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
// Set an accuracy level. The higher, the better for energy.
self.locationManagerTest.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
// Enable automatic pausing
self.locationManagerTest.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
// Specify the type of activity your app is currently performing
self.locationManagerTest.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;
// Enable background location updates
self.locationManagerTest.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
// Start location updates
[self.locationManagerTest startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Note that background location updates needs different privileges

Answer (score 0):

in Capabilities/Background modes/ turn on location updates 
and info.plist add this key "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description"
hope this helped